# MySQL - Getting data from separate tables and sorting by their dates

Tags: mysql

I have two separate tables, each containing items that have a 'date' field.  I'm trying to figure out how to list all items from both tables together (where year_id = 3) and sort them by date.

Here is the code for the "important_dates" table:

```
CREATE TABLE important_dates (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  year_id tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  date date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO important_dates (id, year_id, title, date)
VALUES
    (1,3,'Cannes Film Festival','2015-05-24'),
    (2,3,'Toronto Film Festival','2015-09-10'),
    (3,3,'Venice Film Festival','2015-09-12'),
    (4,3,'People\'s Choice Awards','2016-01-06'),
    (5,3,'Golden Globe Awards','2016-01-10'),
    (6,3,'Independent Spirit Awards','2016-02-20'),
    (7,3,'Razzies','2016-02-20'),
    (8,3,'Oscars','2016-02-21');
```

Here is the code for the "movies" table:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  year_id int(2) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  release_date date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO movies (id, year_id, title, release_date)
VALUES
    (1,3,'The Hunger Games: Catching Fire','2013-11-22'),
    (2,3,'Man of Steel','2013-06-14'),
    (3,1,'Star Trek Into Darkness','2013-05-16'),
    (4,3,'The Great Gatsby','2013-05-10');
```

The desired output is something like this:

```
2013-05-10:  The Great Gatsby
2013-06-14:  Man of Steel
2013-11-22:  The Hunger Games: Catching Fire
2015-05-24:  Cannes Film Festival
2015-09-10:  Toronto Film Festival
2015-09-12:  Venice Film Festival
2016-01-06:  People's Choice Awards
2016-01-10:  Golden Globe Awards
2016-02-20:  Independent Spirit Awards
2016-02-20:  Razzies
2016-02-21:  Oscars
```

I've tried using joins and subqueries and I just can't figure it out. and I know it's probably simple.  Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT date AS DATE, title AS TITLE
FROM important_date 
WHERE year_id=3

UNION

SELECT release_date AS DATE, title AS TITLE
FROM movies
WHERE year_id=3
) AS result
ORDER BY DATE
```

Comment: This is great, wasn't aware of UNION.  I think this is what I'll use, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you crete a mysql view to combine two table records:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_movies;                                                                                                                         
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_movies AS
SELECT id,year_id,title,`date` from important_dates
union all
SELECT id,year_id,title,release_date from movies
```

then select you wanted results from view_movies

```
 select * from view_movies where year_id = 3 order by `date` asc
```

Hope this can help you !

Comment: I've been wondering how to use views for some time now and this makes a whole lot of sense. Thanks!